# With Redis set to allkeys-lfu eviction, can I specify that a specific key should NEVER be evicted?

Tags: redis

I'm using Redis with a `allkeys-lfu` set in configuration for eviction.

However there's one key that I want to make sure is never evicted, can I manually set a "protect" on that key so it will never be evicted under any circumstance, even if it's almost never used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you'll need to solve this by setting the policy to one of the `volatile-*` policies, and set an arbitrarily large TTL on all keys *except* the one you want "protected".

That said, most often than not, it is simpler to use two dedicated databases, each configured per the requirements for the dataset that it stores.